# How many single-elimination tournament brackets are there?

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

Given that $n$ is a power of 2, how many *unique* single-elimination tournament brackets are there with $n$ players?

A single-elimination tournament bracket looks like this: (courtesy of Wikipedia) [image]

Two single-elimination tournament brackets are considered different if at least one of the following conditions is held:

1. There exists a game featuring different players in one of them.
2. There exists a game in each tournament featuring the same players but with a different result.

This implies that the order of players inside each tournament game is irrelevant.

As a base case, when $n = 2$ there are two possible tournaments - each corresponding to a different winner in a single game.

I have a deep suspicion (based partially on a recursive solution) that the answer to the question is $n!$, but I'm having difficulty grasping this intuitively.

Is there a combinatoric proof for why the answer is $n!$?

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** Create a bijection between the $n!$ ways of arranging $n$ teams in a line, and the ways of arranging teams in the bracket (along with a winner in each round).

> There are $n-1$ games. If we know the loser of each game, then the entire elimination tournament can be decided.